# Different behaviour with constexpr function in g++-7.0 / access to hardware

Tags: c++, constexpr, reinterpret-cast

I use the following code to get access to some MCU registers.

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct MCU {
    struct Timer {
        volatile uint8_t r1;
        template<int N> struct Address;
    };
};
template<>
struct MCU::Timer::Address<0> {
    static constexpr uint8_t value = 0x25;
};

template<typename Component, int Number>
constexpr Component* getBaseAddr() {
    return reinterpret_cast<Component*>(Component::template Address<Number>::value);
}

struct Test {
    static void foo() {
        p->r1 = 42;    
    }
    static constexpr auto p = getBaseAddr<MCU::Timer, 0>();
};

int main() {
    Test::foo();

    while(true) {}
}
```

In avr-g++ 6.2.1 this works fine. But now with avr-g++ 7.0 I get the error:

```
in constexpr expansion of 'getBaseAddr<MCU::Timer, 0>()'
bm10a.cc:23:58: error: value '37u' of type 'MCU::Timer*' is not a constant expression
     static constexpr auto p = getBaseAddr<MCU::Timer, 0>();
```

I came to the conclusion, that version 6.2.1 is not confroming and 7.0 is! reinterpret_cast leads to non-constexpr expressions.

So, is there any solution to declare a register address as a constexpr?

Comment: This builds for me in C++11, C++14 and C++1z modes with bog-standard GCC 6.2.0. [GCC 7's C++17 support is more thorough, though](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z). Can you clarify which language you're trying to use? Then we can track down whether this is something C++ itself has changed.

Comment: Hang on... this code does not have 43 lines in it... are you telling porkies? Please tell me I didn't just waste 20 minutes of my Friday evening!

Comment: Also GCC 7 is just pre-release trunk, so what's the _actual_ version you're using? Give a build date or `-v` output.

Comment: Can repro with current GCC 7 snapshot on Godbolt, using the above code.

Comment: Seems you're not even there. Okay good luck!

Comment: I used avr-g++ (GCC) 7.0.0 20161113 (experimental)

Comment: Is there any reason why `getBaseAddr` is `constexpr`. Being `inline` should be enough (and change `constexpr` to `const` recursively). Or do I miss something?

Comment: Its because the constexpr member p in Test.

Comment: You have responded too fast... See my updated comment. `static const auto p` should be enough?

Comment: I tried that: this leads to usage of an memory location for the static data member, I checked the asm listing.

Comment: Then an inline function `p()` instead of the static data member would be enough...

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution according to phil1970 would be using getBaseAddr() as inline function or an alias name for that:

```
struct Test {
    static void foo() {
        p()->r1 = 42;    
    }
    static constexpr auto p = getBaseAddr<MCU::Timer, 0>;
};
```